# Exchange on Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, exchange

I have updated my Samsung S4 to android 5.0.1. I have exchange client that eats all my battery. In office I use exchange via wifi and out office via mobile network. Previous Android version was working in both cases without problems. Lollipop in office wifi case fails to connects to exchange server and tries for many times. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache in recovery, clearing exchange app data and cache in app manager in settings and if all else fails backup and factory reset from setting. Google any instructions you don't understand. Good luck.

Comment: P. S.  Lollipop has a lot of bugs and battery drain is a big one. Hopefully, if nothing else factory reset will fix it but, it might not. I believe there is a way to downgrade to kitkat (Google it). Again, good luck